# Python: Efficiently convert non-negative integers to between 0 and 1

Tags: python, performance, numpy, math, computer-science

What is an efficient way to convert a list of integers to between 0 and 1 like:

```
[0] -> [0]
[9] -> [0.9]
[9, 19] -> [0.09, 0.19]
[9, 19, 1000] -> [0.0009, 0.0019, 0.1]
```

I'm thinking:

```
def integer_to_0_1(numpy_array):
    divisor = 10 ** len(str(np.max(numpy_array)))
    return numpy_array/divisor
```

## Reason

I'm creating an ID in a pandas dataframe from 2 other columns, but I want the ID to be sortable. So instead of creating the ID as a str like `"col1_col2"`, I thought if I make it a number like `col1.col2`, it is easily sortable and order information is not lost. E.g.

```
---------------              ------------
| col1 | col2 |              | ID       |
| 0    | 0    |      ->      | 0        | 
| 0    | 110  |              | 0.110    |
| 2332 | 3    |              | 2332.003 |
```

Comment: It's an awkward-looking transformation to need in the first place. Where does the list of integers come from in the first place?

Comment: Is your current code causing performance issues?

Comment: I'm creating an ID in a pandas dataframe from 2 other columns, but I want the ID to be sortable. So instead of creating the ID as a str like `"col1_col2"`, I thought if I make it a number like `col1.col2`, it is easily sortable and order information is not lost.

Comment: What should be done if one of the numbers is zero? If one is negative?

Comment: Use `factor=10**-len(...)` then multiply may be a bit faster than division. Also can you assume all elements are non negative?

Answer (score 0):

Following is a way to map a list of values to [0,1]. (0 and 1 are inclusive)

```
def convert(numpy_array):
    return (numpy_array- np.min(numpy_array))/(np.max(numpy_array) - np.min(numpy_array))
```

You can map the array `[3, 4, 5, 2, 7]` as follows.

```
[0.2 0.4 0.6 0.  1. ]
```